# How do default template arguments work?

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

I know questions about the syntax of template default arguments have been asked alot.

Usually, the answer (in sync with my understanding of how it should work) is to use something like that:

```
template <class T = SomeDefault> class T1 {};
```

Recently I wanted to check which map implementation Boost uses in its `mapped_vector`. And found the following snippet:

```
template<class T, class A>
class mapped_vector:
```

Apparently, there is no default binding for the argument `A`, but also apparently, I can instantiate a `mapped_vector<int>` just fine. Obviosuly a default argument is inferred somehow, but how?

edit: Just to be precise, I am talking about line 279 in [this file](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/ublas/vector_sparse.hpp)

Comment: This class template could be declared with actual default template arguments somewhere before definition

Comment: The default argument is likely assigned in the declaration in some header.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp#L105)

Comment: Thanks. No at least I see the declaration. Could you provide an answer about how and why exactly this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line [here](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/master/include/boost/numeric/ublas/fwd.hpp#L105) (@Xeo's link) **declares** the template.
The line in your link **defines** it. Note : you **can't** specify **a** default again in the definition, if you decided to have a declaration.

This works: (Boost's version)

```
template<typename T = int> class A;
template<typename T> class A {};
```

[This won't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61c4f655598ab7b1):

```
template<typename T = bool> class A;
template<typename T = int> class A {};
```

[This neither](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b035ccc70f747609):

```
template<typename T = int> class A;
template<typename T = int> class A {};
```

Note that you have to declare it in **either** one. [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/957ece0516e3e383):

```
template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T = int> class A {};
```

Although a default can only be declared once, they don't have to be all declared in the same part. [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ba2215def4b724), but please don't do that:

```
template<class T, class U = bool> class A;
template<class T = int, class U> class A {};
```

... With no limit, really. [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74584911c486646d): (blame - or thank - @Xeo)

```
template<class T, class U, class V = double> class A;
template<class T, class U = bool, class V> class A;
template<class T = int, class U, class V> class A {};
```

And of course, you're not forced to include a declaration. [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98c1eb62fe937c75):

```
template<typename T = int> class A {};
```